# Prove that any field $F$ containing $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ also contains $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that any field $F$ containing $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ also contains $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$.

I started by taking $(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^2=2\sqrt{ab}+a+b$ and want to conclude that $\sqrt{ab}\in F$ but am unsure of this. Then I took $\sqrt{ab}(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})=a\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}b\rightarrow b\sqrt{a}+a\sqrt{b}\in F$ and I know this one is because it is of the form $x\sqrt{a}+y\sqrt{b}\in F$. Thus $1\cdot \sqrt{a}+0\cdot \sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a}\in F$ and$ 0\cdot \sqrt{a}+1\cdot \sqrt{b}=\sqrt{b}\in F$. I think I have shown what is needed.

Comment: Just because $b\sqrt a + a \sqrt b \in F$ does it really mean that for any $x$ and $y$ we have $x\sqrt a + y \sqrt b \in F$? You assume this when you replace $x$ and $y$ with $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Probably $a,b\in F$ have to be added to the hypothesis. It doesn't look to me that $\sqrt{\pi}$ is an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{e}+\sqrt{\pi})$.

Comment: You have shown that $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\in F $ and $b\sqrt{a}+a\sqrt{b}\in F $. This is in fact sufficient, because multiplying first by $a$ or $b$ and subtracting, if $a\neq b$, you can immediately show that $(a-b)\sqrt{a}$ and $(a-b)\sqrt{b}$ are inside it as well. Then you are not far from the conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good start by showing that $a \sqrt{b} + b\sqrt{a} \in F$, but this does not show that $x\sqrt{a} + y\sqrt{b} \in F$ for an arbitrary choice of $x$ and $y$ ($a$ and $b$ are **fixed** constants).

What you want to do is add something to $a \sqrt{b} + b\sqrt{a}$ to cancel out one of the roots. Like maybe a multiple $x(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$ (here you can choose $x$ to be what you need).

Comment: So if I am to show $x(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$ where $x=0$ then $0\in F$ (and then show $1\in F$) and I can use it to show $1\cdot \sqrt{a}+0\cdot \sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a}\in F$?

Comment: Oh like if $x=-b$ then $(b\sqrt{a}+a\sqrt{b})-b\sqrt{a}-b\sqrt{b}=(a-b)\sqrt{b}$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b} = (a-b)(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})^{-1}$

Comment: I apologize I don't follow how this helps. Could you explain a little more

Comment: Once you know that the field F contains $\alpha = \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$ and $\beta = \sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}$ then it will also contain $\sqrt{a} = (\alpha + \beta) / 2$ and $\sqrt{b} = (\alpha - \beta) / 2$. I suppose there is an implicit assumption here that F does not have characteristic 2.